# How to apply inner join in this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written a stored procedure, my table contains 2 foreign keys from same table, `DISTRICTS`.

Scenario: I am passing a person's job record, which should contain his initial working city and district and then current city and district. Now I want to show district names of both but I am confused in joins because it picks data from same districts table

Stored procedure:

```
select 
    ServiceInfo.pk_ServiceInfo_ServiceInfoID, 
    ServiceInfo.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_CurrentDistrictID,
    ServiceInfo.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_InitialDistrictID,
    Districts.DistrictName
from 
    ServiceInfo
join 
    Districts on Districts.pk_Districts_DistrictID = ServiceInfo.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_CurrentDistrictID
join 
    PersonalInfo on PersonalInfo.pk_PersonalInfo_ID = ServiceInfo.fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID
```

Comment: Table aliases, i.e. distrincts d1 ... districts d2

Comment: sir if you could edit my post, I am totally naive about this and on very short deadline

Comment: please see my answer, if you actually want to perform operations please edit your post and add sample data and expected result (as tables). I only formatted your code for aliases, for you to read it easier

Comment: sir, i want to show DISTRICT NAME for each FK i.e. for ServiceInfo.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_CurrentDistrictID, and for ServiceInfo.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_InitialDistrictID,

Comment: both stores different data,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to join on the districts table a second time. Join once with the working city and once with the current city.  Try this:

```
select 
    ServiceInfo.pk_ServiceInfo_ServiceInfoID, 
    ServiceInfo.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_CurrentDistrictID,
    currentdistrict.DistrictName,
    ServiceInfo.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_InitialDistrictID,
    initialdistrict.DistrictName
from 
    ServiceInfo
join 
    Districts currentdistrict on Districts.pk_Districts_DistrictID = ServiceInfo.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_CurrentDistrictID
join 
    Districts initialdistrict on Districts.pk_Districts_DistrictID = ServiceInfo.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_InitialDistrictID
join 
    PersonalInfo on PersonalInfo.pk_PersonalInfo_ID = ServiceInfo.fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID
```

You will notice how I have used a table alias for the district table to show which versin is looking up current, and which version is looking up initial.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select s.pk_ServiceInfo_ServiceInfoID, 
       s.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_CurrentDistrictID,
       s.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_InitialDistrictID,
       d1.DistrictName as CurrentDistrictName,
       d2.DistrictName as InitialDistrictName
from ServiceInfo si 
     join PersonalInfo p on p.pk_PersonalInfo_ID = s.fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo
     join Districts d1 on d1.pk_Districts_DistrictID = s.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_CurrentDistrictID 
     join Districts d2 on d2.pk_Districts_DistrictID = s.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_InitialDistrictID
```

Notice that I used an alias on each table and made sure each alias was used every place the table name would have been used, including the `ON` portion of the joins.

Depending on your circumstance, you may want to make the joins to the **Districts** table be `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. This would be if you wanted to see the information from **ServiceInfo** and/or **PersonalInfo** tables even if there were no records in the **Districts** table for the values in the two foreign key fields. Currently, if either foreign key is missing for a person/service, no record will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would use aliases.

```
SELECT s.pk_ServiceInfo_ServiceInfoID,
       s.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_CurrentDistrictID, 
       s.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_InitialDistrictID,
       d.DistrictName
FROM ServiceInfo s
JOIN Districts d
ON d.pk_Districts_DistrictID = s.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_CurrentDistrictID
JOIN PersonalInfo p
ON p.pk_PersonalInfo_ID= s.fk_PersonalInfo_ServiceInfo_PID
```

Do you have to modify the query in some way, or you just wanted to have an easier time to read?

Comment: sir it's not working that way, I want to show 2 districts, it's showing only one

Comment: sir, i want to show DISTRICT NAME for each FK i.e. for ServiceInfo.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_CurrentDistrictID, and for ServiceInfo.fk_Districts_ServiceInfo_InitialDistrictID